# React-Redux Update Form (PUT request) issue

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, react-redux, put

I am trying to update a form but something is not working as it should. After I click Update, the updated information is logged in the console, but it seems that the Redux side of the state management is not working. I am not getting any errors in the console, but neither my action UPDATE_POST is visible in Redux Dev Tools on Chrome.

Here is the code:

The UpdateForm component:

```
import { useState , useEffect} from "react";
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import jsonPlaceholder from "../apis/jsonPlaceholder";
import {updatePost} from '../actions'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const UpdateForm = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const history = useHistory();
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [post, setPost] = useState({});
    const [title, setTitle] = useState(post.title);
    const [body, setBody] = useState(post.body);
    const [author, setAuthor] = useState(post.author);

    const fetchPost = async () => {
        const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get(`/posts/${id}`)
        console.log(response.data)
        setPost(response.data)
        setTitle(response.data.title)
        setBody(response.data.body)
        setAuthor(response.data.author)
        return response.data
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPost();
    }, [])
    

    const handleUpdate = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const post = { title, body, author }
        dispatch(updatePost(post))
        console.log('post', post)//updated post is logged in console
        history.push('/')
    }

    console.log("title", title)

    return ( 
        <div className="create">
            <h2>Update Blog</h2>
            <form>
                <label>Blog title:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    required 
                    defaultValue={title}
                    onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                    />
                <label>Blog body:</label>
                <textarea
                    required
                    defaultValue={body}
                    onChange={(e) => setBody(e.target.value)}
                ></textarea>
                <label>Author:</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    required
                    defaultValue={author}
                    onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
                    />
                <button onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );

}
 
export default UpdateForm;
```

The action:

```
export const updatePost = (post) => async dispatch => {
    const res = await jsonPlaceholder.put(`posts/update/${post._id}`);
    dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_POST,
        payload: res.data
    })
}
```

And the reducer:

```
import { ADD_POST, DELETE_POST, UPDATE_POST } from '../actions/types';

const postReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_POST:
            return state.concat([action.data]);
        case UPDATE_POST:
            return {
                ...state,
                post: action.data
            }
        case DELETE_POST:
            return state.filter((post)=>post.id !== action.id);
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default postReducer;
```

Here is the node.js/express server side of the request:

```
router.put('/update/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let post = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
            title: req.body.title,
            body: req.body.body,
            author: req.author.body
        })
        console.log('server', post)
        return res.json(post)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error')
    }
})
```

I am now getting server error (500), and if I remove the line author: req.author.body, I am not getting the error. The code on the front still does not work.

Comment: you code looks good. Can you put a `console.log(res)` just after `const res = await jsonPlaceholder.put('posts/update/${post._id}');`.

Comment: It seems that there is a server error too. Here is the request. 
router.put('/update/:id', async (req, res) => {
 try {
  let post = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
   title: req.body.title,
   body: req.body.body,
   author: req.author.body
  })
  console.log('server', post)
  return res.json(post)
 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error.message);
  res.status(500).send('Server Error')
 }
})

Comment: Btw, this is what I get when I console log the response: url: "posts/update/undefined", method: "put", headers: {…}, baseURL: "http://localhost:500   and the response.data object which is wrong (it returns an object with a different id than the one clicked)

Comment: replace `author: req.author.body` by `author: req.body.author` and check that `res.data` is correct into your frontend code

Comment: Uhh thanks for spotting that. I replaced it, and now it works fine on Postman, except that I need to send the request two times (the first time it returns null, and the second time it returns the data).

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispatch the *updatePost* action, not call it directly. You're missing *useDispatch* call.

Here's a link to React Redux documentation covering it:

https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch

Example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

export const CounterComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{value}</span>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'increment-counter' })}>
        Increment counter
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[**UPDATE**]

Just noticed that your *updatePost* action is an higher order function so once you add the call to *useDispatch* you'll need to change the call to *updatePost* from

```
updatePost(post)
```

to

```
updatePost(post)(dispatch)
```

To be honest I would probably go with a book action creator and move the API call to the component itself. If you're interested in async actions I would suggest looking into react-thunk, it is fairly easy to begin with.

[**UPDATE 2**]

There seem to be a typo in the express code.

```
req.author.body
```

should be

```
req.body.author
```

**[UPDATE 3]**

The *post* object in the *updatePost* does not contain the *_id* field (check your *handleUpdate* function) thus you're getting the *url: "posts/update/undefined"*.

Comment: I just did it and I updated the code. Now I can see the action being dispatched in the Redux Dev Tools, but I still don't get my update changes saved to the database. I am not getting any request errors in the console. Maybe I am not doing something right in the action or the reducer?

Comment: Did you also see the updated answer? Noticed that after writing the original one.

Comment: Yes, I tried with both: dispatch(updatePost(post)) and updatePost(post)(dispatch) but there was no difference. It is still not working.

Comment: I would check whether the promise returned by the jsonPlaceholder actually resolves as suggested in the comment to the original post.

Comment: Is the promise resolving on the front end part?

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are directly calling your actions instead of dispatching it

import **`useDispatch`** and use it like this

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
```

**UpdateForm.js**

```
const UpdateForm = () => {
    ....
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    .....

    const handleUpdate = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const post = { title, body, author }
        dispatch(updatePost(post))           // dispatch like this     
        console.log('post', post)//updated post is logged in console
        history.push('/')
    }

    console.log("title", title)

    return ( 
        <div className="create">
           .......
        </div>
    );

}
 
export default UpdateForm;
```

**reducer**

instead of `action.payload`, you're accessing `action.data`

```
case UPDATE_POST:
        return {
         ...state,
         post: action.payload     
       }
```

Comment: I just did it. I updated the question, you can see the changes. Now I get the action in the Redux Dev Tools which means it gets dispatched, but I still don't get the updates saved. I am not getting any console error neither.

Comment: @Monika can you share your response data structure

Comment: here it is author: "Irena"
body: null
createdAt: "2021-03-18T10:15:13.750Z"
title: null
updatedAt: "2021-03-21T16:48:52.852Z"
__v: 0
_id: "605328314500da477ccd39e0"